# MySQL - Take two tables and return results that don't exist in one

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to take two tables, check if someone is scheduled to work for a certain day of the week, and if so, drop them from the results. I want to end up with only those that aren't scheduled for, let's say Saturday. They may be scheduled for other days of the week in schedule_recurring, but I don't care. I just care if they're on the specific day I'm looking at.

I have two tables. For simplicity's sake, let's say:

schedule_recurring:

```
ID, Date_Start, Employee_ID, Date_End
```

employees:

```
ID, FirstName, LastName
```

How the holy hell would I take this and create a SQL statement that would provide me with everyone NOT available on the day I'm looking at, regardless if they work another day of the week. I keep getting every single employee, or damn near close to that.

My goal would be to see if someone works a specific day of the week, if they do, I don't care if they're scheduled for another day of the week, I want them off the results.

Amateur SQL statement below:

```
SELECT 
    schedule_recurring.Date_Start, 
    employees.ID, 
    employees.FirstName, 
    employees.LastName
FROM schedule_recurring, employees
WHERE DAYNAME(Date_Start) != DAYNAME('2014-01-20') and 
      DATE(Date_End) > DATE(NOW()) AND 
      Employee_ID != employees.ID
GROUP BY employees.ID
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What you are expecting ? If I am not wrong, you are expecting the employee on a particular date.

Comment: Use Join which will give the expected result,but you are using Cartesian type of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN instead of multi-FROM, and filter the non-NULLs out:

```
SELECT 
    schedule_recurring.Date_Start, 
    employees.ID, 
    employees.FirstName, 
    employees.LastName
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN schedule_recurring ON schedule_recurring.Employee_ID = employees.ID
  AND DAYNAME(Date_Start) = DAYNAME('2014-01-20')
WHERE schedule_recurring.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: You sir are friggin' wizard. This appears to be exactly what I was looking for. Any SQL books/tutorials you would recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN, or read this JOIN Syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

```
SELECT sc.Date_Start, em.ID, em.FirstName, .em.LastName 
FROM schedule_recurring AS sc 
LEFT JOIN employees AS em ON(em.ID != sc.Employee_ID) 
WHERE DAYNAME(sc.Date_Start) != DAYNAME('2014-01-20') and DATE(sc.Date_End) > DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY em.ID
```

P/s: Why `Employee_ID != employees.ID` but you still select from two table ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
SELECT e.ID,e.FirstName,e.LastName,s.Date_Start
FROM schedule_recurring s 
LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.ID = s.Employee_ID 
WHERE DATE(s.Date_Start) != DATE('2014-01-20') and (DATE(s.Date_End) > DATE(NOW()))
```